# contains quotation mark java

Tags: java, string, quotation-marks

how to I add  an argument to check if a string contains ONE quotation mark ? I tried to escape the character but it doesn't work

```
words[i].contains()
```

EDIT: my bad, got some unclosed brackets, works fine now

Comment: `words[i].contains("\"");`

Comment: isn't `words[i].contains("\"")` working ?

Answer (score 5):

```
words[i].matches("[^\"]*\"[^\"]*")
```

That is: any non-quotes, a quote, any non-quotes.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
words[i].split("\"").length - 1
```

That would give you the amount of `"`s in your string. Therefore, just use:

```
if (words[i].split("\"").length == 2) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Why split when the requirement is `to contain one` ?

Comment: @Shark because `contains` can't tell you how many there are. the OP said exactly one.

Comment: why do you use split and not regex?

Comment: @om-nom-nom Again, regex can't tell you how many `"`s there are. The OP said he wanted exactly 1.

Comment: No, it **can** say if there is exactly one mark, e.g. something like `[^"]*\"[^"]*`

Comment: this is far easier to understand than regex.

Comment: @OliverWatkins yep, but this more likely far less performant too

Comment: i would hazard a guess that both approaches would still be under 1 millisecond. What you don't want to do is premature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the first quotation mark exists, and then check if the second one doesn't. <strike>It's much faster than using matches or split.</strike>

```
int index = words[i].indexOf('\"');
if (index != -1 && words[i].indexOf('\"', index + 1) == -1){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: "much faster?" yeah... about a ten nanosecond gain off 30 nanoseconds or something. You won't ever notice the difference

Answer (score 0):

To check number or quotes you can also use length of string after removing `"`.

```
int quotesNumber = words[i].length() - words[i].replace("\"", "").length();
if (quotesNumber == 1){
    //do stuff
}
```