# How would I check if a line from a text file contains quotation marks?

Tags: java, string

I'm reading a text file that contains a line, e.g. "20 name "Andrew""
and trying to check if the line contains quotation marks after "name" but it returns false when using line.contains("\""). How would I check if the line contains quotation marks with a string between them?

P:S Whenever I print the line out to the console I get: 20 name ‚ÄúAndrew‚Äú
but when I check if the line contains "‚Äú", it returns false, why is this?

Comment: You'll need a regular expression if you're checking for any string within quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [contains quotation mark java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037903/contains-quotation-mark-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the console prints `‚ÄúAndrew‚Äú`, you're probably not using the regular quotation mark. It looks like a fancier unicode quotation, which might look normal (when printed somewhere that supports unicode), but isn't the normal " character. You should go through each character in the String and do

```
for(int i = 0;i < str.length(); i++)
   System.out.println((int)str.charAt(i));
```

You'll see the actual unicode value of the characters.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and found out that the weird characters are; 8218, 196 and 250